# Use angular-cli with multiple path proxy matching

Tags: angular, angular-cli, webpack-dev-server, http-proxy-middleware

How can I define multiple paths to proxy in my proxy.conf.json?
The [angular-cli proxy documentation](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/proxy.md) on github looks like you can only have one path (/api):

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost:3000",
    "secure": false
  }
}
```

But when I look into the [webpack proxy](https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html#proxy) or the [http-proxy-middleware](https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware) documentation, I see it should be possible to define multiple paths (/api-v1 and /api-v2):

```
// Multiple entry
proxy: [
  {
    context: ['/api-v1/**', '/api-v2/**'],
    target: 'https://other-server.example.com',
    secure: false
  }
]
```

But I don't understand how I can get this into the proxy.conf.json.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/6ad057d28cf432ff0c67d3fcf9fc9a51aa5c43a5/aio/content/guide/build.md#proxy-multiple-entries

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use the following syntax in your proxy.conf.json:

```
[
  {
    "context": ["/api-v1/**", "/api-v2/**"],
    "target": "https://other-server.example.com",
    "secure": false
  }
]
```

Actual syntax that works is as below:

```
[
    {
        "context": [
            "/api",
            "/other-uri"
        ],
        "target": "http://localhost:8080",
        "secure": false
    }
]
```

Comment: Works, but where is this syntax documented?

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/proxy.md

Comment: This github link is now dead.. :/

Answer (score 4):

The syntax for multiple entries (using context) is documented here:
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/proxy.md#multiple-entries

```
const PROXY_CONFIG = [
    {
        context: [
            "/my",
            "/many",
            "/endpoints",
            "/i",
            "/need",
            "/to",
            "/proxy"
        ],
        target: "http://localhost:3000",
        secure: false
    }
]

module.exports = PROXY_CONFIG;
```

This also requires that you **rename** your config from **.json** to **.js** and point your run command at the new file.

For me the **context syntax** doesn't quite work (I assume because I want to use **wildcards**). So I came up with the following solution which allows you to generate a config:

```
module.exports = [
  "/my",
  "/many",
  "/endpoints",
  "/i",
  "/need",
  "/to",
  "/proxy",
  "/folder/*"
].reduce(function (config, src) {
  config[src] = {
    "target": "http://localhost:3000",
    "secure": false
  };
  return config;
}, {});
```

This got the job done for me. (note that this still requires that your rename your proxy.conf.json to proxy.conf.js and edit your run command to point at the renamed file)

Comment: this github link no longer works

Answer (score 1):

As of 2021-03, here is the answer:

1. In the CLI configuration file, `angular.json`, add/modify the proxy file:

   ```
   ...
   "architect": {
     "serve": {
       "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
       "options": {
         "browserTarget": "your-application-name:build",
         "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.js"
       },
   ...
   ```
2. Create a `proxy.conf.js` such as:

   ```
   const PROXY_CONFIG = [
       {
           context: [
               "/my",
               "/many",
               "/endpoints",
               "/i",
               "/need",
               "/to",
               "/proxy"
           ],
           target: "http://localhost:3000",
           secure: false
       }
   ]
   module.exports = PROXY_CONFIG;
   ```

Note it is .**js**, not .json.

[Official Details](https://angular.io/guide/build#proxy-multiple-entries)

**Update, 2021-07-08** It takes `.js` or `.json`. Former one is better as it allows `// comment`.

For SSL:

```
"target" : "https://localhost:3001", 
        "changeOrigin": true,       // solves CORS Error in F12
        "logLevel": "debug",        //"info": prints out in console
        "rejectUnauthorzied": true, // must be false if not specify here
        "secure": false,            // PROD must be "true", but DEV false else "UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE"
        "strictSSL": true,          // must be false if not specify here
        "withCredentials": true     // required for Angular to send in cookie
```